# 1 email address 2 subject and 2 forms in magento

Tags: forms, magento, contacts

I have an email address that is set for CONTACT US form and CUSTOM form (like WARRANTY form) that is created from CONTACT US form
[Multiple Contact Forms on Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327037/multiple-contact-forms-on-magento).

I want to separate this email with variant subject (when send email from contact us form subject should be contact and when send email from CUSTOM/WARRANTY form subject of email should be WARRANTY)

What is the best solution for this? How do I do?

Answer (score 1):

For send Email to Multiple recipients in Contact Us Magento, you can tray this way.

Step One, you can Find this line on app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/Controllers/IndexController.php

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );
```

and modified to bellow :

```
                $recipients = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT);
                if ($recipients)
                {
                        $recipients = explode(";",$recipients);
                        if(count($recipients))
                        {
            foreach($recipients as $recipient) {

            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    $recipient,
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
                }
         }
     }
}
```

And don't forget to comment validation javascript on app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/system.xml

Find this line :

```
<recipient_email translate="label">
    <label>Send Emails To</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
<!--<validate>validate-email</validate>-->
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</recipient_email>
```

Give comment to this line `<validate>validate-email</validate>`

this code works for me in magento 1.7.0.2 . I hope this help your problem.. :D

Don't forget to save and clear cache..

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add a hidden form field which contain the email subject.

Then go to admin -> Transaction Email and change the Template Subject to

> {{var data.formsubject}}

Add a hidden field to each form

```
<input type="hidden" name="formsubject" value="Subject Here" />
```

Read more @ [Customizing Transactional Emails](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customizing-transactional-emails)