# Custom Form not showing up in magento

Tags: forms, magento

I am having difficulty getting a form to show on a magento store I am working on. the site already has a contact form so I've copied the form.phtml file and renamed it brochure.phtml. 
I've created a static page on the CMS section and added this line of code based on [this qusetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327037/multiple-contact-forms-on-magento)

```
 {{block type="core/template"  template="contacts/brochure.phtml"}}
```

When I view the page though nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong? I've never used magento before so please be as detailed in your answers if you can.

Comment: Not sure if it's the reason it's not showing up, but add a name="brochure" after the block type. I think it's required.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'nothing shows up', do you get a blank white page or a page with header and footer without the form content? Did you clear cache? Also did you click 'Show / Hide Editor' to hide the editor before entering the code above?

Comment: My bad there was no issue at all only my own stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

CMS -> Pages ->Select your page -> Select "Content" on the left side navigation

Post this code there

{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/brochure.phtml"}}

make sure your brochure.phtml file is in the same folder as the form.phtml file.  If your CMS page is coming up with the header, body format and the rest of the website layout but the middle content section is plain white then it is not loading your brochure.phtml.  If this is the case I would then try loading the default form, so replace "brochure.phtml" with "form.phtml" and reload the page.  If you see the default form then you know your brochure.phtml file is in the wrong location.

Hope this fixes your problem.